# Why is my ajax call displaying the output in the php file instead of redirecting to the html?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have written a series of ajax functions that fetch data from an php file. The problem is one of the functions redirects to the php file to fetch data but does not return to the html page to insert the data.

In this case the following code is to get a table from a php file

```
  var display_results = $("#display_results").val();
  var url3 = "../server/insert_tests.php?analyses=";
     $.ajax({
          type: "GET", 
          url: url3 + display_results,           
          success: function(data) {
            $("#analyses").html(data);
          }
        });
```

And fetches the following data from the file `insert_tests.php`:

```
if (isset($_GET['analyses'])) {
    require 'dbh.php';
    $id = $_GET['analyses'];

    $samples = "SELECT * FROM samples_database JOIN storage_database on samples_database.storage_location=storage_database.id WHERE samples_database.order_id=$id AND samples_database.micro_analysis<>'';";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $samples);

    $output3 = '';

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {

        $output3 .= '
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Sample Number</th>
        <th>Client ID</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Storage</th>            
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Time Stamp</th>   
        <th colspan="1"></th>            
        </tr>                           
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

            $output3 .= '
            <tr> 
            <td>'.$row['env_sam_id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['c_sam_id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['sample_type'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['storage_name'].'</td>            
            <td>'.$row['s_status'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['s_date1'].' (<i>'.$row['s_time1'].'</i>)</td>   
            <td><a class="get_result edittablebtn show_submit_button" href="../server/insert_tests.php?query='.$row['sample_id'].'">Enter Results</a></td>                   
            </tr>';
        } 
        $output3 .= '</tbody>';
    } 
    echo $output3;
}
```

This is relevant because I suspect this `<a class="get_result edittablebtn show_submit_button" href="../server/insert_tests.php?query='.$row['sample_id'].'">Enter Results</a>` is causing the downstream problem.

The table created by this function has varying number of rows and clicking on the button on the table will reveal information pertaining to the data in that row. This is done with this function:

```
   $('.get_result').click(function (event) { 
     event.preventDefault(); 

     var url = $(this).attr('href');

     $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#tests").html(data);
      }
    });
   });
```

And fetches the following data from the same `insert_tests.php` file:

```
if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
    require 'dbh.php';

    $id = $_GET['query'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE sample_id=$id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $input1 = $input['micro_analysis'];
    $env_sam_id = $input['env_sam_id'];
    $c_sam_id = $input['c_sam_id'];
    $order_id = $input['order_id'];
    $rows = explode(',', $input1);

    if (count($rows) > 0 ) {
        $output .= '
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
        <th>Tests ('.$env_sam_id.' <i>'.$c_sam_id.'</i>)</th>
        <th>Detected</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM microbiology_analysis_database WHERE id=$row"; 
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
            $input2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
            $analysis = $input2['m_analysis'];


            $query3 = "SELECT * FROM results_database WHERE m_analysis_id=$row AND order_id=$order_id AND sample_id=$id;"; 
            $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
            $input3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
            $result_id = $input3['id'];
            $result = $input3['result'];
            $detected = $input3['detected'];

            $output .= 
            '<tr>
            <td>
            <input class="hidden" name="result_id[]" id="result_id" value="'.$result_id.'" readonly>
            <input class="hidden" name="m_analysis_id[]" id="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row.'" readonly>
            <input class="hidden" name="order_id[]" id="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'" readonly>
            <input class="hidden" name="sample_id[]" id="sample_id" value="'.$id.'" readonly></td>


            <td>'.$analysis.'</td>
            <td><input name="detected[]" class="result_input" type="text" id="detected" value="'.$detected.'"></td>
            <td><input name="result[]" class="result_input" type="text" id="result" value="'.$result.'"></td>
            </tr>';
        }
        $output .= '</tbody>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

The problem is that this table from the last function does not return the data in the html page but rather shows an un-formatted table in the url that is used to redirect (`href="../server/insert_tests.php?query='.$row['sample_id'].'"`).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how it might be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know, the `$('.get_result').click(function ...)` is to bind the function in parentheses to the click event of all elements of `get_result` class.

However, this call is only applied to the **existing** elements when the event binding is called. In your case, since the table with `<a class="get_result">` tags is loaded by AJAX and injected **after**. The event binding above didn't applied.

The simple solution is to run the event binding after each and every time the table is injected by AJAX.

Comment: So by placing the click function in the success section of the first ajax function?

Comment: @roelofco yes, that's how I would do it